# How to set cookie using javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

Setting cokie works property in FF and Chrome but not works in IE

```
function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value +';path=/'+ ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        }



function checkCookie()
    {
    var newsletter=getCookie("newsletter5");
    if (newsletter!=null && newsletter!="")
      {      
      }
    else 
      {
      setCookie("newsletter5", 2000);
      timeMsg();
      }
    }

setCookie("newsletter5", 2000);
```

When I decrease security protection lower than average it works but it should be working on sefault settings

Answer (score 1):

```
    setCookie("name","value",expiryDate,"/");




    // cookie.js file
    var cookieToday = new Date(); 
    var expiryDate = new Date(cookieToday.getTime() + 
    (365 *86400000)); // a year

/* Cookie functions originally by Bill Dortsch */

function setCookie (name,value,expires,path,theDomain,secure) { 
   value = escape(value);
   var theCookie = name + "=" + value + 
   ((expires)    ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") + 
   ((path)       ? "; path="    + path   : "") + 
   ((theDomain)  ? "; domain="  + theDomain : "") + 
   ((secure)     ? "; secure"            : ""); 
   document.cookie = theCookie;
} 

function getCookie(Name) { 
   var search = Name + "=" 
   if (document.cookie.length > 0) { // if there are any cookies 
      var offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search) 
      if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists 
         offset += search.length 
         // set index of beginning of value 
         var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset) 
         // set index of end of cookie value 
         if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length 
         return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end)) 
      } 
   } 
} 
function delCookie(name,path,domain) {
   if (getCookie(name)) document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path)   ? ";path="   + path   : "") +
      ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

Comment: I have found this solution before, tried it but not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I think that main problem is to set value to `document.cookie`
When I set some value and check in IE is not asigned.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling cookies and JavaScript in your browser

https://my.sph.harvard.edu/jsp/misc/java_cook.jsp

Comment: It is not good solution becouse I try set up popup in shop. Will be problem for IE users.